# time stamp XXXX s in the future issue - touch command (Linux)

Tags: linux, unix, debian, timestamp, touch

When I untar a `tar.gz` file on Debian Lenny, I get the such outputs:

```
tar: openssl-1.0.1e/apps/openssl.cnf: time stamp 2013-02-11 15:26:04 is 1360584537.139999998 s in the future
openssl-1.0.1e/apps/openssl-vms.cnf
tar: openssl-1.0.1e/apps/openssl-vms.cnf: time stamp 2013-02-11 15:26:04 is 1360584537.129999998 s in the future
openssl-1.0.1e/apps/passwd.c
```

I see that the time stamp of the file is in the future comparing the system's time. I use `touch` as below to change the time stamp of the file, and `stat` shows that the time stamp of the file is the system's current time, then I attempt to untar the file, but I still get the same time stamp problem (as above).

```
ts7500:/home# touch -am openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz 
ts7500:/home# stat openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz 
  File: `openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz'
  Size: 4459777         Blocks: 8736       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 2b09h/11017d    Inode: 40802       Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 1970-01-01 03:15:24.000000000 +0000
Modify: 1970-01-01 03:15:24.000000000 +0000
Change: 1970-01-01 03:15:24.000000000 +0000
ts7500:/home# date
Thu Jan  1 03:15:48 UTC 1970
ts7500:/home# tar xvf openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
```

I know that I can solve the problem by changing the system's time by `date -s "08 JUN 2013 00:19:00"` or use `NTP`. But I wonder, why changing the time stamp of the file by `touch` did not work? how should I have changed the time stamp of the file, so that I would not have that warning?

If you want to see the file system:

```
ts7500:/home# blkid
/dev/nbd6: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="01E8-4C7D" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/nbd8: UUID="236b63b3-15db-40c3-bc5f-e4b7c4b10751" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/nbd9: UUID="5b13aa84-e589-41a7-84cf-2d0d6bf2a9cd" TYPE="ext3" 
ts7500:/home# df -Th
Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs        tmpfs     31M  4.0K   31M   1% /lib/init/rw
udev         tmpfs     10M  160K  9.9M   2% /dev
tmpfs        tmpfs     31M     0   31M   0% /dev/shm
rootfs      rootfs    3.3G  1.7G  1.5G  53% /
/dev/root     ext2    2.0M  1.7M  311K  85% /initrd
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It did not work because you changed the timestamp of the *archive*, not of the files it contains. If you run `stat` on the `tar.gz` file you will find that the time was changed correctly. `touch` cannot access the files stored within the archive until you extract them so they were left unchanged.

In any case, this should not be a problem, just untar the archive, then change the timestamp of the files:

```
mkdir foo
mv openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz foo/
cd foo/
tar xvvzf openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
find . -exec touch -am '{}' \;
```

Comment: Hi , 
if suppose i make compress tar file from many different folders and then again untar them to different folders and while untar i get this timestamp delay message so do my untar data will be wrong in my different folders ?
For EX- tar -cvf filename.tar P*/fs.6
             tar -xvf filename.tar 
This tar -xvf will distribute in P* folder 
but do this tar --touch -xvf will distribute wrong data into P* folder ?

Answer (score 6):

You can extract your tar file with the --touch parameter to do this automatically.

```
tar --touch -xvf openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
```

Comment: Hi , 
if suppose i make compress tar file from many different folders and then again untar them to different folders and while untar i get this timestamp delay message so do my untar data will be wrong in my different folders ?
For EX- tar -cvf filename.tar P*/fs.6
             tar -xvf filename.tar 
This tar -xvf will distribute in P* folder 
but do this tar --touch -xvf will distribute wrong data into P* folder ?